# Error while fetching data from Snowflake to SQL Server OpenQuery

Tags: sql, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing issue to run select query to Snowflack to SQL server through linkserver.
Query having one column which has a large length. it's simple select query
I can run query in snowflake webUI or snowsql bit while running from openquery from SSMS i am getting below error

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "" returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.".
> Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 7
> Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].DESCRIPTION" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "".

Query is like

```
SELECT *  FROM OPENQUERY([Linkserver],'select DESCRIPTION from My_DB.PUBLIC.product;')
```

the column datatype is varchar(125507). I tried to cast it, but did not help.
Please let me know if anyone face this kind of issue.